# Acentos en Bash

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Cuando genero una consulta desde mi base de datos, me devuelve una información, la cual la guardo en una variable y luego la envío por mail desde el bash usando "mail".

El problema que tengo es que, como algunas palabras tienen acentos, el Bash no lo reconoce y me explota, ignorando toda esa fila. ¿Alguien sabe cómo evitar esto?

Probé con:

`OBSERVACIONES_ARREGLADO=$(echo "$OBSERVACIONES" |   sed  'y/áÁàÀãÃâÂéÉêÊíÍóÓõÕôÔúÚñÑçÇªº/aAaAaAaAeEeEiIoOoOoOuUnNcCao/')`

Pero se me murió de risa jaja

Comment: ¿Te da problema un simple "echo" o el envío del mail?

Comment: @JoséMiguelSA Ya lo pude solucionar! use un iconv para convertir de Europa Occidental a UTF-8..por mas que la db decia ser utf-8 lo hice igual y funciono

Comment: @JuanManuel245 Por favor, agrega la solución que encontraste como respuesta y acéptala una vez hayan pasado 48 horas. De esa manera el sistema reconocerá esta pregunta como resuelta y podrá ser de utilidad a personas con problemas similares.

Comment: Creo que tienes que configurar tu terminal para usar utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Algo que he hecho es hacer consultas y exportarlas de alguna manera a un archivo, ya sea un csv, etc.

Ya que tienes ese csv puedes pasarle un `$ file <archivo que exportaste>` y ver ahí la codificación.

Después, esa codificación la utilizas en el comando:

`$ iconv -f <la codificación que obtuviste> -t <a la que la quieres pasar> <archivo que exportaste> > archivo_nueva_codificacion.txt`

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316986/how-to-convert-iso8859-15-to-utf8) hay buenos ejemplos a una pregunta relacionada.

Sólo como comentario adicional, sé que lo pediste para Linux, pero si en algún momento estás haciendo un servicio web que consulta de una base de datos y tiene caracteres extraños, podrías generar una función semejante a esta en python que yo utilizo. Claro que según el lenguaje de tu preferencia, sólo quiero a dar a entender la idea.

```
def func_encode_to_utf(x):
    if 'utf-8' not in chardet.detect(x)['encoding'].lower():
        x = x.decode(chardet.detect(x)['encoding']).encode('utf-8')
    return x
```

Y la mecánica es la misma, conocer la codificación de un caracter y luego, si no es "UTF-8" (en mi caso), la paso a "UTF-8"

Comment: Generalmente se suele omitir el prompt cuando se comparte un comando en un bloque de codigo. En tu caso, todos los **$** estan sobrando.

Comment: ¿"Generalmente"?, bueno, yo los pongo para diferenciar de lo que se escribe en una shell de en otro lado, digamos, la consola de python. Si ese "generalmente"  no los pone, deberá tener sus razones.